# Rxjs, Combine last query result for multiple group (combine switchMap with groupBy)

Tags: rxjs

I have an issue using the operator. Basically I have multiple payslips and I want to keep a debounce for each payslip and trigger a query. I want to subscribe to only the last query that succeed for a **specific payslip** and if a new request is triggered for this payslip before the previous one finished, I want to cancel the previous one.

Here's a sample marble diagram for what i'm looking for:

-----1----1-----1----3----3----3----3-----1---3---1---3---1------>

(magic operators for which I'm unclear)

-------------------1-------------------3-----1---3---1---3---1--->

I have debounce and query, which I like, but it does this:

-----1----1-----1----3----3----3----3-----1---3---1---3---1------>

debounce

-------------------1-------------------3--------------------1---->

```
    .pipe(
        groupBy(payslip => payslip._id),
        map(group =>
          group.pipe(
            debounceTime(200),
            switchMap(payslip => httpQuery)
          )
        ),
        mergeAll()
      )
```

With the current solution, the merge all is grouping the switch map thus canceling even for other group. Is there a way to do what I want ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am struggling to find anything wrong with your code or it's outcomes.

I have put the following test code in the [ThinkRx playground](https://thinkrx.io/)

```
const { rxObserver } = require('api/v0.3');
const { zip, timer, from, of } = require('rxjs');
const { take, map, groupBy, mergeAll, debounceTime, delay, switchMap } = 
require('rxjs/operators');

zip(
  timer(0, 50),
  from([1,1,1,3,3,3,3,1,3,1,3,1]),
).pipe(
  map(([_,i])=>i),
  groupBy(i=>i),
   map(group => group.pipe(
    debounceTime(0),
    switchMap(i=>of(i).pipe(delay(0))),  // simulates http request with know duration
  )),
mergeAll(),
).subscribe(rxObserver());
```

With debounce and time-for-http-request both 0 the result is:
[image]

With time-for-http-request = 60  (note the time scale is longer):
[image]

And then with debounce = 10:
[image]

Is it possible in your code that the http request simply takes longer than the time between the requests, so the switchMap is correctly cancelling the earlier one?

Comment: This is working well finally, after looking at your comment and checking everything again I realize my issue was coming from my payslip _id not being unique in certain cases... So stupid from me to not have seen this before...
It's working very well, thank you very much for your help. I didn't know https://thinkrx.io/, it will help me a lot to work with rxjs in the future. Thank you again :) and sorry for your time !